# Does the number of imported modules in python effect memory and performance?

Tags: python, memory, module

When importing modules in python, is there a memory difference when you import a single module from a package eg: *from math import ceil* vs the whole package eg: *import math*? I guess what I am really asking is whether or not it slows processing down when the script is run?

Comment: I think that this depends on how the package's `__init__.py` is configured ... *but*, python imports are generally fast  and the memory footprint is generally small (unless you have some module level intense processing going on).  It's probably not really worth worrying about unless you have some really stringent hardware constraints...

Comment: In python we generally write codes that make the file/module importable.
Thus if you go on using `import math` or `os` in multiple files it will lead to code duplication and if will expose so many functions that you don't even know or you don't even want to import. Thus it is a good habit to use  `from os import path` instead of `import os`.

Comment: @Shrey a running Python interpreter will import at most one instance of a module no matter how many times it is imported. The `from x import y` just promotes y to the current lexical scope; that is, whether you have to call it s `math.sin()` or just `sin()`. It otherwise has *no effect at all* on code duplication or even imported code. Thus, `from math import sin` still imports `math.cos()`, `math.log()` and all the rest.

Comment: @msw Thanks. So if we want `sin()` function to be called many a times we should opt for `from math import sin`. Just thinking should we treat this as a feature or a bug?

Comment: It is definitely a feature, but its overuse is error-prone. There is a tiny extra cost in that `math.sin` takes two dictionary lookups instead of one, however if the top-level namespace becomes very full you'll probably lose that tiny gain in looking through a much larger namespace. But this is Python, so nano-performance ought not be a priority. If I am writing a trigonometry heavy program then `from math import *` may well make my code easier to read. In general though, `module.object` or even `module.submodule.object` is easier on the reader and that's what counts.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no difference between those. [Raymond Hettinger](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/620993578118967296), one of the core Python developers, recently tweeted this:

> #python tip: from-imports don't save memory. They execute and cache the entire module just like a regular import.

Comment: Then why have from-imports at all?

Comment: @ajsp so that you do not have to access things as - `module.name` ?